# Kafka module missing on syslog-ng.

Tags: syslog-ng, kafka

I'm trying to install syslog-ng and its kafka module. I'm using docker debian:latest for this if that matters.

After running 'apt-get install syslog-ng' the syslog-ng can't reach the kafka module even though they are both installed as I can see in `dpkg -l`:

```
ii  syslog-ng                         3.8.1-1                    all          Enhanced system logging daemon (metapackage)
ii  syslog-ng-core                    3.8.1-1                    amd64        Enhanced system logging daemon (core)
(...)
ii  syslog-ng-mod-java                3.8.1-1                    amd64        Enhanced system logging daemon (Java destination)
ii  syslog-ng-mod-java-common-lib     3.8.1-1                    amd64        Enhanced system logging daemon (Java module common library)
ii  syslog-ng-mod-journal             3.8.1-1                    amd64        Enhanced system logging daemon (systemd journal plugin)
ii  syslog-ng-mod-json                3.8.1-1                    amd64        Enhanced system logging daemon (JSON plugin)
ii  syslog-ng-mod-kafka               3.8.1-1                    amd64        Enhanced system logging daemon (Kafka destination)
(...)
```

But running `syslog-ng --version` I don't see kafka in the list of Available-modules and syslog itself is failing on `Can't find class; class_name='org.syslog_ng.kafka.KafkaDestination'` exception.

Any clue on what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you check the prerequisites in the docs? https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.8-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.8-guide-admin/html/destination-kafka-prerequisites.html